# "What are you going to do WITH me?" OR "What are you going to do TO me?"

Tags: word-usage, phrases, prepositions, differences

I am always perplexed about the nuances between these 2 sayings.

> 1. What are you going to do with me?
> 2. What are you going to do to me?

Just imagine the context to be a fearful victim asking the kidnapper what will happen to him.

Comment: Either could be appropriate.  Are they imagining being held for ransom (1) or tortured (2)?

Answer (score 0):

The differences are often small or none. But there are sometimes perceptible nuances. The numbers of meanings of *with* and *to* in dictionaries are so large that it is almost impossible to find the set of meanings peculiar to one or the other. My answer is therefore suggestive and partial. I hope that others will add to it.

I cook food *with* a saucepan. The saucepan is instrumental in my cooking.

If I hold you for ransom I use you as a bargaining tool to extort money.  I shall be extorting *with* you as my tool.

In these cases, *with* associates loosely the subject and object as a new subject concept for a verb that has another object (I and the saucepan cooking the food, I and my victim extorting the money).

In the case of *to* it is difficult to make the instrumental connections to a new object as above. There is often only a subject-object connection. I shall hit you. I shall tie you up. I shall use you (as a tool to extort money). I am the subject of these sentences and these are the things that your body or mind will experience as the object of my actions.

Answer (score -1):

I have changed the sentences to SVO format to make them clearer examples.

**With** = in conjunction or combination with; together with.

1 **You are going to do what with me?** Here, the suggestion is that the kidnappers and the victim will participate together in some activity in which they will both be engaged. The implication is that the victim will also play his part and is necessary.

Semantically, "me" is the theme.

**To me:** This is a beneficial dative (an adverbial) in that the “to” indicates that the action of the verb goes from the subject of the sentence to the object of the preposition: “He gives it to me.”

2 **You are going to do what to me?** Here the suggestion is that the victim will simply be the recipient of the action of the kidnappers.

Semantically, "you" is the theme.

Comment: It is difficult to imagine a realistic scenario in which the 'kidnappers and the victim will participate together in some activity in which they will both be engaged'. *To do something with someone* in the sense that the OP has in mind is an idiom; *with* in it does not have the same meaning as in *to go to the theatre with someone*.

Comment: @jsw29 My answer should be understood literally: the kidnappers participate *with* the victim in the same action - "willingly" is grammatically irrelevant. I don't see an idiom. "With" has **one** overarching meaning and that encompasses many nuances, but all require some sort of combination.